# Undefined Index: total

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una operacion con array para que me arroje la suma total de los productos seleccionados en un carrito de compras y me arroja el error undefined index.

```php
 public static function statsCarrito(){
        $stats= array(
            'count => 0',
            'total => 0'
        );
        if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
            $stats['count'] = count($_SESSION['carrito']);

            foreach ($_SESSION['carrito'] as $producto){
                $stats['total'] += $producto['precio']*$producto['unidades'];
            }
        }

        return $stats;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Estas definiendo mal el array. Cambia

```
 $stats= array(
            'count => 0',
            'total => 0'
        );
```

por

```
 $stats= array(
            'count' => '0',
            'total' => '0'
        );
```